# Is JSONP supported in the new Flickr OAuth API?

Tags: oauth, jsonp, flickr

I searched for the JSONP usages of Flickr's OAuth.  Let me know whether it's supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only 2 supported methods, you cannot use OAuth for a whole login process using JSONP.

But, even if it's deprecated, the old API still exists, is usable and supports JSONP: [deprecated flickr auth API](https://secure.flickr.com/services/api/auth.spec.html).

Comment: I know that old api exists and it is deprecated. I am already using it. I am plannign to move to OAUTH as old implementation is not going to be there in the near future. Any ways thanks for your response.

Comment: Using local proxy for initial two requests for now :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, yes: http://www.flickr.com/services/api/explore/flickr.auth.oauth.getAccessToken

JSONP is JSON with padding, meaning wrapped in a function. Flicker oauth's looks like this:

```
jsonFlickrApi({ "auth": { 
                  "access_token": { 
                    "oauth_token": "", 
                    "oauth_token_secret": "" 
                  } 
                }, "stat": "ok" })
```

Edit (since I was downvoted):

This is the proper use of the flickr oauth API: http://www.flickr.com/services/api/auth.oauth.html everything is covered on signing and access token and how to get that token from a request token. If someone is serious about implementing the oauth process what you would get back as JSONP is the snippet I posted above. You can test it all from this link http://www.flickr.com/services/api/explore/flickr.auth.oauth.getAccessToken

Comment: This request is for exchanging token used in old API with the one that can be used for OAuth. I want the oath hand shaking between client and server with JSONP

Comment: *This* is flickr's oauth API as fas I as know check their docs at http://www.flickr.com/services/api/ under auth.oauth. If you wanted a full server-client demo interaction displaying how to use flickr oauth's API you should have asked for that not that "wether it's supported". If I get around to it I'll post back later.

Comment: There are only 2 methods in this API: one for exchanging and old token, the other for checking the token. The whole process does not appear to be supported by this API.

Comment: I think you are both confusing what JSONP is. JSONP is a format. In this case a response format. If you call flickr's API with &format=json you get JSONP back, calling it with &format=json&nojsoncallback=1 you get regular JSON back.

Comment: Yes, but you cannot call methods and get a JSONP response from flickr OAuth API except for 2 methods. The whole process of identifying an user cannot be done with JSONP responses.