# URL not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: ajax, jquery, flickr

I am trying to implement OAUTH for accessing Flickr APIs. My AJAX call to flickr.com keeps failing.

Sample Error Message:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.flickr.com/services/oauth        /request_token?oauth_callback=oob&oauth…signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1368375405647&oauth_version=1.0. Origin http://localhost:8080 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Initially I used chrome and read the html file as file://path. I used to get the error 'null not allowed by access-control-allow-origin'. I solved this problem by copying the html file to 'local IIS server', 'local python webserver' and then a 'remote webserver'. I created python web server using > python -m http.server 8080'

I realize my cross browser call to flickr.com using XMLHttpRequest is failing. I tried by various solutions suggested in this forum:

1. Using newer Chrome 26.0.1410.64 m, which I guess supports CORS
2. I launched chrome with --disable-web-security
3. I created a web server using python -m http.server 8080 on local machine and then on a remote machine and copied the html file to the site
4. I copied file to a local MSFT IIS server
5. I defined URL in etc/hosts file to avoid numeric IP

I still get the same error (with relevant URL in the error message)

code clipping:

```
urlString="http://www.flickr.com/services/oauth/request_token?"+
        "oauth_callback="+"oob"+'&'+
        "oauth_consumer_key="+consumerKey+'&'+
        "oauth_nonce="+nonce+'&'+
        "oauth_signature="+esignature+'&'+
    "oauth_signature_method="+macAlgorithm+'&'+
        "oauth_timestamp="+timeStamp+'&'+
        "oauth_version=1.0";


$.ajax({
   url: urlString,
   success:function(data){
    alert(data);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to CORS work, *both ends* must enable it.

The first end is the **browser**, and, as you are using Chrome 26.*, yours is ok.

The second end is the **server**:

Before making a `GET` request to a domain different than the one the page is on, the browser sends an `OPTIONS` request to that domain. In response to this request, the server should include some **headers** that tell if a cross-domain request (`GET`, `POST` or other) is allowed.

One of those headers is `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.

So when you run your page from your file system (`file://` "protocol"), the `OPTIONS` means something like *"Flickr, can I make a cross-domain call to you? I'm calling from `null`"*. Flickr does not recognize that domain as allowed and returns the error you are getting.

Same way, when you run your page from your local server, the `OPTIONS` says *"(...) I'm calling from `localhost:8080`"*. Flickr does not recognize that domain as allowed as well.

#### The solution:

I don't know the Flickr oauth service, but I know that, as any other service, to make a CORS call to it, the page must be in a domain allowed by it. From your tests, I'm guessing Flickr does't allow many other domains.

But... an alternative to CORS is JSONP. I did a little research, Flickr oauth seems to support it.

Check this page for details: http://www.flickr.com/services/api/explore/flickr.auth.oauth.getAccessToken
There's another question talking about that specific subject:
[Is JSONP supported in the new Flickr OAuth API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7596563/is-jsonp-supported-in-the-new-flickr-oauth-api)

About JSONP, this can get you started: [How to make a JSONP request from Javascript without JQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6132796/how-to-make-a-jsonp-request-from-javascript-without-jquery)

Comment: Very useful insight. I installed fiddler to monitor the messages. The call to www.flickr.com is being.

Comment: @RamuAZ The call to flickr.com is being what?

Comment: www.flickr.com is returning the correct response for the API, but chrome is blocking it. The response is: 
HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
..........
oauth_callback_confirmed=true&oauth_token=72157633483477361-04bb6d43983dd596&oauth_token_secret=5178df6644e5d70d.

I am researching how to send the OPTIONS or set appropriate headers.
Thanks for your answer. It has put me on the right track.

Comment: How are you testing this? (You don't need to send the `OPTIONS` yourself, Chrome will do that behind the curtains.) It seems like you are testing with another program (it should work with other program).

Comment: Some research seems to indicate flickr oauth does not support CORS. I am trying to use JSONP to get my response, but Chrome is reporting an error although flickr seems to return correct result, but without wrapper. I think I am not using JSONP correctly.

  $.ajax({
  url: urlString,
  cache: true, 
  dataType: "jsonp",
  jsonpCallback: "oobx",
  success:function(data){
    alert("Ramu success");
  },
  error: function (a, b, c){
     alert("Ramu Error"+a+b+c);
  }
  })

Comment: continued...  flickr returns but without wrapper function:      result was : oauth_callback_confirmed=true&oauth_token=72157633498154161-87b2fd2d66882e7f&oauth_token_secret=49b9d86c4010a51c

Comment: How are you printing this code? Maybe uou should start a new question altogether.

Comment: Hey there, how did this issue go?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to implement Oauth 1.0 through just javascript without any server side script. Since the flickr's new authentication process is based on Oauth 1.0a. You got to use a server-side script.

I tried to send the token request using JSONP in FireFox with CORS on(using a third-party add-on) and it worked fine. But without using any add-ons, it's not possible as the response from flickr is in text format(not in a JSON format) and the request fails.

You can either use server-side code for token request. OR Use the deprecated flickr API for authentication.